# Формованное тесто перед конечной обработкой

Tags: названия

Как называется изделие из теста перед запеканием, жарением, перед конечной его обработкой, приданием готового вида - готовое тесто, форма для выпекания, заготовка?

Comment: Приведите пример предложения (ситуации), когда вам было необходимо знать, как называется "формованое" тесто перед конечной обработкой. Это специальная лексика в пищевой промышленности, почему вас это вообще интересует (ведь это не ваша, кажется, специальность)? И почему вы пишете одну букву Н в этом слове? Пожалуйста, расскажите, просто интересно, зачем вам это?

Comment: Извините, не обратил внимание на "ова", отсутствие приставки и несовершенный вид побудили написать с одной "н". Меня интересуют разные области знаний, роды деятельности. Я указываю признаки слова, совершенно случайно меня заинтересовавшего, которое я хотел бы применить в речи, я стремлюсь отыскать его и таким образом расширить свой лексикон.

Comment: Я не могу понять, в чем неясность заключается? В зависимости от блюда это слово может различаться? Я недостаточное количество признаков искомого слова описал?

Comment: Владимир, лично я за правку вопроса не голосовала.  Формулировка вам предложена  стандартная, которая используется  для этого случая. Ключевое слово - проблема. Так в чем она заключается?  Возможно, участникам не понравился ваш комментарий о случайной заинтересованности этим словом. Ведь это нельзя назвать проблемой. В любом случае, вы должны были сами поискать в Сети нужный материал. Вы искали и не нашли? И как вы собираетесь применить это слово в своей речи?

Comment: Давайте немного пофанатазируем и представим такую ситуацию (это шутка, пожалуйста, не обижайтесь).  Вы собираетесь испечь пирожки и говорите детям: "А теперь тестовые заготовки мы ставим в духовой шкаф. Вам понятно?" - Да, папочка, мы их будем тестировать, да?

Comment: То есть на данном ресурсе задают вопросы исключительно для того, чтобы решить какую-либо проблему, волнующую автора, которой необходимо быть насущной, наличной и нацеленной на приложение в определенном случае, месте? Мне-то казалось, что отвечающих не волнует личная жизнь и заботы авторов вопросов. Не знаю, перестала ли тестовая заготовка быть тестовой заготовкой, если бы я указал, в каком случае хотел бы употребить это словосочетание.

Comment: Я полагаю, что на форуме должны обсуждаться проблемные вопросы,  которые интересны широкой аудитории и содержат в себе проблему, то есть сложны или неоднозначны в своем решении. К специальной лексике  относится множество терминов, и было бы странным обсуждать их здесь безо всякой причины для этого.  Конечно, есть исключения, но ваш интерес к таким словам должен быть мотивирован. Например, вы читаете художественную литературу и вам попадается неизвестное слово. Вы не можете найти его в словаре и тогда обращаетесь на форум за помощью. В этом случае вопрос становится и интересным, и проблемным.

Comment: Впрочем, это моё мнение, возможно модераторы вам объяснят всё лучше.

Comment: Нужно ли указывать, как вы хотите УПОТРЕБИТЬ это слово? На эту тему у Роберта Шекли есть  рассказ  «Из луковицы в морковь» Герой рассказа  - милый, приятный человек, которого все всегда оттирали и задевали. Однажды он решил взять напрокат пишущую машинку. Клерк запросил за нее немыслимую сумму, залог в виде паспорта и добавил, что ему необходимо знать, как клиент собираетесь ИСПОЛЬЗОВАТЬ аппарат.  И т.д.  Похожая ситуация, не правда ли?  Вы ведь тоже считаете такое требование абсурдным?  Но использовать  "тестовую заготовку" сложно в обычной жизни, если только вы не собираетесь стать пекарем.

Comment: Не могу сказать, что аналогия справедлива. Ведь герой, как планировалось, возвратит машинку. Специально оговаривать на данном ресурсе, что я собираюсь использовать слово по назначению или не по назначению нет необходимости, я думаю. Смысл имеет указывать контекст в случае, если от него зависит искомое слово и если они будут различаться. Вопросы я чаще задаю по словам, значение которых мною понято не вполне, в случаях, когда определения в словарях и примеры употребления не дают полногг и ясного представления о них. Специальное же слово найти не всегда просто по признакам.

Answer (score 0):

Это называется "тестовая заготовка":

https://baker-group.net/technology-and-recipes/technology-confectionery-industry/changes-dough-pieces-for-baking.html

Форма для выпекания - в неё кладут тесто, чтобы получить печенье, кексы, пироги особой формы.